# Get FormDataParam Properties and Attributes

Tags: java, web-services, forms, post, jersey

```
    @POST
    @Path("post")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public Response postCategory(@FormDataParam("text1") String text1,
            @FormDataParam("file1") InputStream file1,
            @FormDataParam("text2") String text2,
            @FormDataParam("file2") InputStream file2) {
        System.out.println("CategoryService.postCategory()");
        System.out.println("text1:" + text1);
        System.out.println("text2:" + text2);

        String uploadedFileLocation = "d://uploaded/test.jpg";
        writeToFile(file1, uploadedFileLocation);

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

With this code I can get **HtmlInputFile** as **InputStream**, **HtmlInputText** as **String**, but I want to get another properties of **HtmlInputText** like `id, name, class` and even more: my dynamic attribute like the following:

```
<input type='text' myattr='myattr-value' name='inpp'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

When a form is submitted (per the [WC3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)) the name and the value are sent to the server.  To get other values I'd recommend creating some additional hidden inputs.

```
<input type="hidden" name="valueOne" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="valueTwo" value="">
```

And some javascript to set those fields on submit.

```
<script>
    document.yourForm.elements["valueOne"].value = "someValue";
    document.yourForm.elements["valueTwo"].value = "someOtherValue";
</script>

<form name="yourForm" method="POST" onSubmit="setValues();">
```

However you may want ask why are id's and classes important to the form submit.  This type of design may couple your backend controllers too tightly to the frontend markup.  This may cause some problems down the line.

Comment: see my scenario: i've a form where users can add number of pictures, (1,5,10 or more, it's unknown) how can i get them at the beckend?

Comment: In this case you should probably fire off multiple posts using ajax rather than try to handle this in a single post.

Comment: Ajax can be wrapped in a submit call.  You just need to structure your callbacks so that the "real" submit happens after the last field is processed.